# Accessing scoped DbContext in singelton hosted service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, backgroundworker, dbcontext

I can't simply inject the DB context so I have to rely on injecting `IServiceScopeFactory` and obtain it from the registered services like this.

```
AppDbContext Context()
{
  using IServiceScope scope = Services.CreateScope();
  return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
}
```

It doesn't work when I invoke it elsewhere like this.

```
async Task Seed(int count)
{
  AppDbContext context = Context();
  ...
  await context.AddAsync(new Thing { ... });
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

According to the error message, the service is disposed. And, indeed, since I'm setting it in the scope of `using` statement, as the method ends, it should be expected. I see two ways to deal with it.

1. Request the service in the same method that talks to the DB.
2. Omit disposal of the context keeping it alive in the singelton.

I dislike both of them. The first one leads to code redundancy. The other one may block the otherwise scoped DB access.

What would be a better option to deal with it?

Initially, I tried to create options and create the DB access internally in my class. However, that stopped working when I started to create migrations, as `dotnet ef migrations add Init` requires the service to be registered in `Program`, hence forcing me to obtain it using the method above.

```
DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> ContextOptions()
{
  DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> builder = new();
  builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("memento");
  //builder.UseSqlServer(a => { });
  return builder.Options;
}
```

Comment: The DbContext is a short living thing. For each operation unit create one, do your work and dispose it.

Comment: The 3. option: do it like asp.net and the controller class. For each request create a scope, get a controller (or any class) instance, let that instance do the job and dispose the scope. The smart part is the injection of the DbContext in that controller (class)

Comment: Disposing the scope, will dispose all scoped services. You will need to work out how you are going to manage the lifetime of that scope. What level of your code most resembles a "unit of work", where the scope should be created & disposed? That's a question I can't answer for you.

Comment: @SirRufo The way I interpret your comment is that you suggest (1), i.e. reobtaining the reference to the service for each operation I do in my class (that talks to the DB). It's a background worker service so it runs forever in an eternal while loop, regularly checking a DB for data. (I agree that a preferred way would be to inject the context but it's not possible since it's scoped while my hosted service is a singleton.)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah, I agree. So, basically, getting a reference to the scoped context for each method that does the unit of work (being option 1), right? I wonder, though, what you mean by the first statement, about all scopes being disposed. The way I expect it to work is that the only the scope I obtain from the injected instance of `IServiceScopeFactory` by calling `Create()` that would be disposed. What do I miss?

Comment: So maybe you want `while(true) { await Task.Delay(...); using var scope = ....; var worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Worker>(); ...}`, so the core of your background loop is actually in a scoped service, with all other dependencies injected as normal. Then when `scope` is disposed, all disposable scoped services will also be disposed.

Comment: Instead of connecting to the db in multiple locations in you code get db in one location and then pass instance to other parts of your code or make the instance static if you are using synchronous methodology (one thread).

Comment: @jdweng That would make the context singleton, right (since it wouldn't be disposed)? I have no problem doing that as suggested but it seems more commonly applied on the basis of *per unit of work*, where each individual unit gets its own, dedicated instance. My worry is that although it works initially, as the service will execute run after run, the old (tiny) sin will accumulate and bite me in the sitting device.

Comment: You have to weigh the advantages and disadvantages of opening database for every query vs keeping the connection open.  It take time to open each connection.  Most apps have a connection pool to avoid opening connection for each query.  The connection pool is build into the Net Data Client classes.  You are using Entity. See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?force_isolation=true&tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant

Comment: The normal solution is to [create a scope around the work that needs it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). Since your service is periodic, I recommend a scope for each time-based invocation. That's what I do for my scheduled services.

Comment: @StephenCleary I tried that out and your suggestion seems to make the most sense, especially given that my worker executes once a few minutes (if not more rarely). Would you mind posting a reply to be accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal solution is to [create a scope around the work that needs it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). Since your service is periodic, I recommend a scope for each time-based invocation. That's what I do for my scheduled services.

After injecting an `IServiceProvider`, you can use that to create a scope and then create whatever "processor" type you need (which, in turn, would inject a `DbContext`):

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    AppDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
  }
}
```

Scopes are quite fast to create; the normal pattern for ASP.NET is to create a new scope for every request.

Comment: I took the liberty to make it less general for the poor dumb-wits such as myself. WHile I got the processor meaning, I suspect that referring to the actual DB context explicitly makes it easier to swallow for a less experienced user, while still providing a gainful info for the others. Feel free to revert if you disagree.