# How to create `DBContext` for continues use

Tags: c#, sqlite, dbcontext

I have a `client - server` application with the access to the `SQLite` database (`DBContext`) on a per web access request base.

```
namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }


        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to sqlite database
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
        }
        
    }
}
```

I need to run a background thread that is accessing the database every hour and send an e-mail to the user, if the time to the user's schedule is less then three hours. I can't re-use per request db context (as above), because it is disposed each time after request is finished.
How can I create `DBContext` (sort of permanent DB access) that would be accessible at any time during runtime of the app.

Comment: DbContexts are designed to be _single use_.  You get a new one, use it for some amount of work, and when finished, _dispose_ of it.  Why do you think you want to hang on to one?

Comment: I need to run background task and send e-mail when some condition of the db record is true. In this case what do I need to do to have some sort of db context to access the database?

Comment: So, create a new one when you need one

Comment: Using scoped services from a singleton service is a common SO question with lots of duplicates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808632/accessing-scoped-dbcontext-in-singelton-hosted-service

Comment: How do I create new DBContext for my thread use?  Can you give me an example. I have tried to get hold of IServiceProvider to get to my DataContext but I am getting exceptions.